# FBX SDK Python, некорректное получение UVs

Tags: python, fbx

У меня есть FBX SDK Python скрипт, который правильно получает вершины и индексы, то есть получая их, правильно строится меш, но при этом неправильно получает UV и Нормали, в чем проблема (неправильно накладываются текстуры и тени)? Может потому что получаю через полигоны?

Script:

```
import sys, os, json, urlparse
sys.path.append( '.../public_html/engine/utils/fbx/lib/Python27_ucs4_x64/' )
from fbx import *

def application( environ, start_response ):

#url path

value = environ[ 'HTTP_HOST' ]+environ[ 'REQUEST_URI' ]
query = urlparse.urlparse(value).query.decode( 'UTF-8', 'strict' )
url = urlparse.parse_qs(query)[ 'url' ][0]

path = '.../public_html/engine/'+url

#initializing file

manager = FbxManager.Create()

IOSettings = FbxIOSettings.Create( manager, 'IOSettings' )
manager.SetIOSettings( IOSettings )

scene = FbxScene.Create( manager, 'Scene' )

importer = FbxImporter.Create( manager, 'Importer' )

status = importer.Initialize( path, -1, IOSettings )

JsonReq = []

if( status != False ):

    #if file exist

    importer.Import( scene )
    importer.Destroy()

    pFbxRootNode = scene.GetRootNode()

    objcount = pFbxRootNode.GetChildCount()

    for i in range( objcount ):

        #for every object

        pFbxChildNode = pFbxRootNode.GetChild( i )
        pMesh = pFbxChildNode.GetNodeAttribute()

        if( pMesh == None ):
            continue

        geometry = FbxGeometryConverter( manager )
        pMesh = geometry.Triangulate( pMesh, True )

        attributeType = pMesh.GetAttributeType();

        if( attributeType != FbxNodeAttribute.eMesh ):
            continue

        polygonCount = pMesh.GetPolygonCount()
        layerCount = pMesh.GetLayerCount()

        indices = pMesh.GetPolygonVertices()
        pVertices = pMesh.GetControlPoints()

        m_vecIndices = indices
        m_vecVertices = []
        m_vecNormals = []
        m_vecUVs = []
        m_vecUVIndices = []
        UVs = []

        #transform

        node = pMesh.GetNode()

        lTmpVector = node.GetGeometricTranslation( FbxNode.eSourcePivot )
        Position = [ lTmpVector[ 0 ], lTmpVector[ 1 ], lTmpVector[ 2 ] ]

        lTmpVector = node.GetGeometricRotation( FbxNode.eSourcePivot )
        Rotation = [ lTmpVector[ 0 ], lTmpVector[ 1 ], lTmpVector[ 2 ] ]

        lTmpVector = node.GetGeometricScaling( FbxNode.eSourcePivot )
        Scale = [ lTmpVector[ 0 ], lTmpVector[ 1 ], lTmpVector[ 2 ] ]

        #vertices

        control_points_count = pMesh.GetControlPointsCount()
        control_points = pVertices

        positions = []

        for z in range( control_points_count ):
            tmp = control_points[ z ]
            tmp = [ tmp[ 0 ], tmp[ 1 ], tmp[ 2 ] ]
            positions.append( tmp )

        if node:
            t = node.GeometricTranslation.Get()
            t = FbxVector4( t[ 0 ], t[ 1 ], t[ 2 ], 1 )
            r = node.GeometricRotation.Get()
            r = FbxVector4( r[ 0 ], r[ 1 ], r[ 2 ], 1 )
            s = node.GeometricScaling.Get()
            s = FbxVector4( s[ 0 ], s[ 1 ], s[ 2 ], 1 )

            hasGeometricTransform = False
            if t[ 0 ] != 0 or t[ 1 ] != 0 or t[ 2 ] != 0 or \
                r[ 0 ] != 0 or r[ 1 ] != 0 or r[ 2 ] != 0 or \
                s[ 0 ] != 1 or s[ 1 ] != 1 or s[ 2 ] != 1:
                    hasGeometricTransform = True

            if hasGeometricTransform:
                geo_transform = FbxMatrix( t, r, s )
            else:
                geo_transform = FbxMatrix()

            transform = None

            if hasGeometricTransform:
                transform = geo_transform

            if transform:
                for z in range( len( positions ) ):
                    v = positions[ z ]
                    position = FbxVector4( v[ 0 ], v[ 1 ], v[ 2 ] )
                    position = transform.MultNormalize( position )
                    positions[ z ] = [ position[ 0 ], position[ 1 ], position[ 2 ] ]

        for z in range( len( positions ) ):
            m_vecVertices.extend( positions[ z ] )

        #normals

        for z in range( layerCount ):

            mesh_normals = pMesh.GetLayer( z ).GetNormals()
            if( not mesh_normals ):
                continue

            normals_array = mesh_normals.GetDirectArray()
            normals_count = normals_array.GetCount()

            if normals_count == 0:
                continue

            normal_values = []

            for l in range( normals_count ):
                normal = normals_array.GetAt( l )
                normal = [ normal[ 0 ], normal[ 1 ], normal[ 2 ] ]
                normal_values.append( normal )

            node = pMesh.GetNode()
            if node:
                t = node.GeometricTranslation.Get()
                t = FbxVector4( t[ 0 ], t[ 1 ], t[ 2 ], 1 )
                r = node.GeometricRotation.Get()
                r = FbxVector4( r[ 0 ], r[ 1 ], r[ 2 ], 1 )
                s = node.GeometricScaling.Get()
                s = FbxVector4( s[ 0 ], s[ 1 ], s[ 2 ], 1 )

                hasGeometricTransform = False
                if t[ 0 ] != 0 or t[ 1 ] != 0 or t[ 2 ] != 0 or \
                   r[ 0 ] != 0 or r[ 1 ] != 0 or r[ 2 ] != 0 or \
                   s[ 0 ] != 1 or s[ 1 ] != 1 or s[ 2 ] != 1:
                    hasGeometricTransform = True

                if hasGeometricTransform:
                    geo_transform = FbxMatrix( t, r, s )
                else:
                    geo_transform = FbxMatrix()

                transform = None

                if hasGeometricTransform:
                    transform = geo_transform

                if transform:
                    t = FbxVector4( 0, 0, 0, 1 )
                    transform.SetRow( 3, t )

                    for l in range( len( normal_values ) ):
                        n = normal_values[ l ]
                        normal = FbxVector4( n[ 0 ], n[ 1 ], n[ 2 ] )
                        normal = transform.MultNormalize( normal )
                        normal.Normalize()
                        normal = [ normal[ 0 ], normal[ 1 ], normal[ 2 ] ]
                        normal_values[ l ] = normal

            m_vecNormals.append( normal_values )

        #UVs

        for z in range( layerCount ):

            mesh_uvs = pMesh.GetLayer( z ).GetUVs()
            if( not mesh_uvs ):
                continue

            uvs_array = mesh_uvs.GetDirectArray()
            uvs_count = uvs_array.GetCount()

            if( uvs_count == 0 ):
                continue

            uv_values = []
            uv_indices = []

            for l in range( uvs_count ):
                uv = uvs_array.GetAt( l )
                uv = [ uv[ 0 ], uv[ 1 ] ]
                uv_values.append( uv )

            vertexId = 0
            for p in range( polygonCount ):

                poly_size = pMesh.GetPolygonSize( p )
                poly_uvs = []

                for v in range( poly_size ):

                    control_point_index = pMesh.GetPolygonVertex( p, v )

                    if mesh_uvs.GetMappingMode() == FbxLayerElement.eByControlPoint:
                        if mesh_uvs.GetReferenceMode() == FbxLayerElement.eDirect:
                            poly_uvs.append(control_point_index)
                        elif mesh_uvs.GetReferenceMode() == FbxLayerElement.eIndexToDirect:
                            index = mesh_uvs.GetIndexArray().GetAt( control_point_index )
                            poly_uvs.append( index )
                    elif mesh_uvs.GetMappingMode() == FbxLayerElement.eByPolygonVertex:
                        uv_texture_index = mesh_uvs.GetIndexArray().GetAt(vertexId)

                        if mesh_uvs.GetReferenceMode() == FbxLayerElement.eDirect or \
                            mesh_uvs.GetReferenceMode() == FbxLayerElement.eIndexToDirect:
                                poly_uvs.append( uv_texture_index )
                    elif mesh_uvs.GetMappingMode() == FbxLayerElement.eByPolygon or \
                        mesh_uvs.GetMappingMode() ==  FbxLayerElement.eAllSame or \
                        mesh_uvs.GetMappingMode() ==  FbxLayerElement.eNone:
                        return '[]'

                    vertexId += 1
                uv_indices.append( poly_uvs )

            UVs.extend( uv_values )
            m_vecUVIndices.extend( uv_indices )

        for z in range( len( m_vecUVIndices ) ):
            for v in range( len( m_vecUVIndices[ z ] ) ):
                m_vecUVs.extend( UVs[ m_vecUVIndices[ z ][ v ] ] )

        #Request

        JsonReq.append( {
                        'indices': m_vecIndices,
                        'normals': m_vecNormals,
                        'UV': m_vecUVs,
                        'vertices': m_vecVertices,
                        'transform': [ Position, Rotation, Scale ]
                        } )

    JsonReq = json.dumps( JsonReq )

status = '200 OK'
response_headers = [ ( 'Content-type','text/plain' ) ]
start_response( status, response_headers )

return JsonReq
```

Comment: Типовая причина таких ошибок как правило неверный порядок чтения и/или последующего использования (значений и/или индексов). Т.е. решение проблемы как правило состоит во внимательном изучении кода в отладчике. Также стоит уточнить входные-выходные форматы.

Comment: А еще такой вопрос, есть вершины UV, а есть UV индексы. Они нужны для получения результирующих UV вершин? Надо поменять вершины относительно индексов?